# Get the WPMU default blog domain

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a network of blogs that link to each other. The problem is when I want to get the primary blog's domain. I need it for things like the the target of the logo when clicked.

I can't seem to find a function in WPMU the retrieves this. I can see the value I want in the wp_site table. I could easily get it with $wpdb, but its a bit over kill, and if there is a function that can get the value already, then I want to use it.

I would prefer a solution that does not use a hardcoded ID as this can change if the root blog is deleted and/or replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `get_blogaddress_by_id(1)`? This would get the URL for the blog with ID 1 (which is the primary blog by default).

Check out `wp-includes/wpmu-functions.php` for similar functions.

Note, this might all change with the codebase merge in 3.0.

UPDATE

If you want the site install blog, use the global object `$current_site` (`$current_site->ID`). If you want the 'dashboard blog', use `get_site_option('dashboard_blog')`.

Comment: I would prefer a solution that does not use an ID as this can change if the root blog is deleted and/or replaced.

Comment: My apologies, I skim read the question and missed the last part. Check my revised answer.

Comment: Whenever I get stuck like this, I do print_r($GLOBALS);die(); somewhere and look at the output to see if I can get the global value I need. You'll be amazed what's there, already ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo 'You are viewing '.get_current_site()->domain;
?>
```

see the [doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_current_site)

Comment: My mistake, this returns the current site, I want the root site.